# Returning Go Generic Type

Tags: go, generics

The following fails to compile on line `res = fmt.Sprintf("%s + %s", i, j)` with the error: `cannot use fmt.Sprintf("%s + %s", i, j) (value of type string) as type T in assignment`

It *does* allow me to return an `int` and the code *does* compile and run if I simply `return i + j`.

I'm missing some fundamental understanding and need to be pointed in the correct direction.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Adder interface {
    string | int
}

func Add[T Adder](i, j T) T {
    var res T

    switch reflect.TypeOf(i).Name() {
    case "int":
        res = i + j
    case "string":
        res = fmt.Sprintf("%s + %s", i, j)
    }

    return res
}
func main() {
    it := Add(3, 4)
    st := Add("one", "two")

    fmt.Println("Int:", it)
    fmt.Println("Str:", st)
}
```

Comment: switch on `any(res).(type)`, to have the compiler statically type-check the code, instead of switching on reflect's type name. Then assert the value back to `T` as shown in the linked question. As for the assignment, the assignment must be valid for all types in `T` type set.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at what `Add` does for strings:

```golang
func Add[string](i, j string) string {
    var res string

    switch reflect.TypeOf(i).Name() {
    case "int":
        res = i + j
    case "string":
        res = fmt.Sprintf("%s + %s", i, j)
    }

    return res
}
```

This is ok. The expression `i + j` just concatenates two strings. Take a look at what `Add` does for `int`:

```golang
func Add[int](i, j int) int {
    var res int

    switch reflect.TypeOf(i).Name() {
    case "int":
        res = i + j
    case "string":
        res = fmt.Sprintf("%s + %s", i, j)
    }

    return res
}
```

This is a type error. It does not matter that the `"string"` branch is never taken at runtime—the entire function must typecheck!

(Note that Go does not actually instantiate generics by inserting the types—but you get the idea.)

Answer (score 1):

The body of the generic function must be valid for all possible types. If `res` is int, the "string" case cannot be compiled. If `res` is string, both cases are valid expressions.

You can try this idea by declaring

```
type Adder interface {
    string 
}
```

and making the necessary changes. You still need to:

```
        res = T(fmt.Sprintf("%s + %s", i, j))
```

Comment: Ah- it makes sense.  Thanks.

However, `res = T(fmt.Sprintf("%s + %s", i, j))` still doesn't work.

Comment: the conversion to `T` fails for the same reason as the assignment fails, as you point out in the first sentence of this answer

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/cWOiMQpEhRS

Comment: This works only after you change the definition of Adder

Comment: after changing `Adder` to one exact type you might as well remove the type parameter altogether and rewrite the signature as `Add(i, j string) string`